# Ansible build a list of dictionaries and append to list within dictionary

Tags: dictionary, ansible

Taking this cut down example set of inventory hostvars:

```
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {
            "host-a.foo.com": {
                "host_domain": "foo.com",
                "subnet_address": "192.168.1.0",
                "subnet_mask": "255.255.254.0"
            },
            "host-b.foo.com": {
                "host_domain": "foo.com",
                "subnet_address": "192.168.2.0",
                "subnet_mask": "255.255.254.0"
            },
            "host-c.bar.com": {
                "host_domain": "bar.com",
                "subnet_address": "192.168.2.0",
                "subnet_mask": "255.255.254.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to produce something representing the following in ansible:

```
[
    {
        "192.168.1.0": {
            "mask": "255.255.254.0",
            "domains": [
                "foo.com"
            ]
        },
        "192.168.2.0": {
            "mask": "255.255.254.0",
            "domains": [
                "foo.com",
                "bar.com"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

So far I have this, but I'm unsure how to append to the domains list for each dictionary item (instead of overwriting it):

```yaml
- name: inventory subnets
  set_fact:
    inventory_subnets: "{{ inventory_subnets | default({}) | combine({
      hostvars[item].subnet_address: {
        'mask': hostvars[item]['subnet_mask'],
        'domains': [
          # How to build this list?
        ]
      }
    }) }}"
  loop: "{{ query('inventory_hostnames', 'all') }}"
```

Is it possible to perform another combine within a dictionary definition somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tasks below

```
- set_fact:
    hostvars_list: "{{ hostvars_list|default([]) +
                       [{'host': item.key}|combine(item.value)] }}"
  loop: "{{ hostvars|dict2items }}"
- set_fact:
    subnets: "{{ subnets|default([]) +
                 [{item.0: {'mask': item.1|json_query('[].subnet_mask')|first,
                            'domains': item.1|json_query('[].host_domain')}}] }}"
  loop: "{{ hostvars_list|groupby('subnet_address') }}"
- debug:
    var: subnets
```

give

```
    "subnets": [
        {
            "192.168.1.0": {
                "domains": [
                    "foo.com"
                ], 
                "mask": "255.255.254.0"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "192.168.2.0": {
                "domains": [
                    "foo.com", 
                    "bar.com"
                ], 
                "mask": "255.255.254.0"
            }
        }
    ]
```